# Entity Framework Class Generation Naming Scheme

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

Is there any way to configure the code Generation naming conventions.  I have a DB with several different schemes.  The classes are being generated as the table names, but several are postfixed with assending numbers. So I have table1, table2, ... tablex.  What I would like is SchemeName1_table, SchemeBlaBla_table, ... SchemeWhatEver_table.

Is this possible with reasonable effort?  I'm using C# in VS2012.

Edit:  I should mention that:

1. The Database already exists and may not be modified.
2. The tables being postfixed are those whose names exist in other schemes.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this. But you can use CodeFirst approach to create mapping of classes to database tables. In this case you have whole control over names of classes and properties

Comment: CodeFirst? The DB exists already, and I decided to go with E.F. because I didn't want to do it all by hand and "reinvent" the DB.

Comment: CodeFirst does not meant create db from code. It means that you create mapping in code. This mapping can be done to existing database. You cannot out of the box change naming conventions for mapping generators of EF.

Comment: Ah.  A misinterpretation... So how do the Classes, Functions, and Procedures get created?